# How to get Wordpress mobile menu to trigger a javascript event based on css class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have code that triggers a slide in / out menu using a css class on a stardard wordpress menu item.  It works fine on desktop but on mobile clicking the same menu link does not trigger the code.

Here is the jquery code:

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var dl_ButtonToggle = $('.dl-btn-toggle');
    var dl_SlideSidebar = $('.dl-slide-sidebar');
    dl_ButtonToggle.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      dl_ButtonToggle.toggleClass('is-opened');
      dl_SlideSidebar.toggleClass('is-opened');
      dl_SlideSidebar.addClass('has-transition');
      dl_SidebarCheck();    
    })
    
    $('.dl-close').click(function() {
      $('.is-opened').removeClass('is-opened');
      dl_SidebarCheck();
    })
});</script>
```

I use the css class  .dl-btn-toggle   on the wordpress menu item to trigger the slide in.

How can I make it work on mobile wordpress menu as well?